# Compute the Jacobi fields for the geodesic variations

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

This is one of my exercise on my notes. I am still stuck and hope someone can help.

We have $p \in M$ and $V,W\in ˇT_p M$.

Compute the Jacobi fields of the following geodesic variations at $s=0$. 
$γ_s(t) = exp_{η(s)}(tV_{η(s)})$, where $η(s) = exp_p (sW)$ and $V_{η(s)} ∈ T_{η(s)}M$ is the parallel transported version of V along η.

Comment: What exactly do you want? If the manifold is not explicit, I do not know that Jacobi field will be in any case explicit.